# Inequality for embedding in Sobolev space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

For $\Omega=(0,1). $Prove that there exists $M>0$ such that
$$||u||_{C^0(\overline{\Omega})}\le M||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}$$
for all $u\in H^1(\Omega).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $u(0)=0$. Then 
$$
u(x)=\int_0^x u'(s)ds=\int_0^1 \textbf{1}_{(0,x)}u'(s)ds.
$$
Now you use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
$$
u(x)\leq \|u'\textbf{1}_{(0,x)}\|_{L^2}=\int_0^1 (u'(s))^2\textbf{1}_{(0,x)}ds\leq \int_0^1 (u'(s))^2 ds.
$$
Right?

Comment: Why you can assume $u(0)$ like that? I also do like your way, but don't think that.

Comment: In general you can't. This is a simpler case. For an unbounded domain you can do the same trick paying with an $L^2$ norm of $u$.

Comment: Let me think how to deal with $u(0)$...

Comment: In particularly, $M$ in someone's essay is $\sqrt{2}$. I'm strongly wondering. The problem is of $u(0)$...

Comment: Mmm i think that i know the origin of this $\sqrt{2}. It's just the unbounded case.

Comment: I use BCS inequality firstly for $|u(0)|+|u'(t)|$ to get $\sqrt{2}$. But this problem still is of $u(0)$...

Comment: Use the fact that there is a continuous extension operator $P \colon H^1(0,1) \to H^1(\mathbb{R})$, and exploit the fact that $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$. See also Brezis, Analyse fonctionnelle, Théorème VIII.7.

Comment: Just this is my new proof, but $M$ must be $\sqrt{6}$ :-( Also, it is in Rafa's proof above.
$$|u(x)|=|u(0)+\int_{0}^{x}u'(t)dt|\le\int_{0}^{1} (|u(0)|+|u'(t)|)dt$$
I use respectively BCS and Holder inequality here, that is,
$$\int_{0}^{1} (|u(0)|+|u'(t)|)dt\le\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{|u(0)|^2+|u'(t)|^2}dt\le\sqrt{2}(\int_{0}^{1}|u(0)|^2+|u'(t)|^2dt)^{1/2}$$
Also, I have
$$|u(0)|\le\sqrt{2}(\int_{0}^{1}|u(x)|^2+|u'(t)|^2dt)^{1/2}\equiv \sqrt{2}||u||_{H^1}$$
Hence, from the former,
$$|u(x)|^2\le 2(|u(0)|^2+\int_{0}^{1}|u'(t)|dt)\le 6||u||^2_{H^1}$$
So $M=\sqrt{6}$.
Is it correct?

Comment: Why is the third line of equations true? By the way, the constant in my proof is exactly 1, isn't it?